# Java socket programming - private network

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I'm working on a small  model of a p2p private network. 
So,
Is there a way to make the server socket choose the clients wanting to connect with it?

Comment: What do you mean? Limit who can connect to the server?

Comment: You can always reject a connection if you do not like it. I.e. establish connection, check remote address and if it does not meet your requirements, close the connection again. Do that until you connect to whoever you wanted to connect to.

Comment: A better approach could be something called Client Authentication via Certificates. The only requirement will be generating certificates and distributing to clients, who must be allowed. !

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca Yes

Comment: @Zabuza - is there a specific method ?

Comment: @ Kris - Thank you very much <3

Comment: Method for what? Dropping a connection? Just `close()` the socket you get from `Socket client = server.accept();`. (Best done with a try-with-resources)